# After restarting, Android plays default notification instead of custom(saved in sharedPreferences)

Tags: java, android, notifications, sharedpreferences, ringtone

The three methods: ringtone(); onActivityResult(); saveRingtone(); do work.
During the first load of the app the fourth method loadRingtone(); works too, it can play repeatingly any sound the user chooses. 
But as the app restarts:
It does save and bring back the string of the User's chosen notification sound. But just as its supposed to play the sound, converted from that string, it plays the default instead.

I used some toasts to check the values.
    Toast.makeText(this,uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this,ringPath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
public void ringtone(View view){
        final Uri currentTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5){
            uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            if (uri == null) {
                uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            }
            sound = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            saveRingtone();
         }
    }
    public void saveRingtone(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Ring, uri.toString());
        editor.apply();
     }
    public void loadRingtone(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        ringPath = sharedPreferences.getString(Ring, "");
        if(ringPath == ""){
            uri =    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         }else {
             uri.parse(ringPath);
         }
         sound = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
         sound.play();
    }
```

Its expected to play the notification that the "sound" variable is set up with in the loadRingtone(); method (not default sound).

Comment: try using RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

Comment: Have you tried to debug the loadRingtone method? What is the result of 'sharedPreferences.getString(Ring, "");' ?

Comment: The method gets different string whenever user chooses different notification. Before restarting app, it does play the chosen notification. After the app restarted, it takes the saved value and sets it as the "sound" variable, and when I tell it to play "sound.play();" it changes its value to the default notification and then plays.